# data.table replace data using values from another data.table, conditionally

Tags: r, data.table

This is similar to [Update values in data.table with values from another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469003/update-values-in-data-table-with-values-from-another-data-table) and [R data.table replacing an index of values from another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749036/r-data-table-replacing-an-index-of-values-from-another-data-table), except in my situation the number of variables is very large so I do not want to list them explicitly.

What I have is a large `data.table` (let's call it `dt_original`) and a smaller `data.table` (let's call it `dt_newdata`) whose IDs are a subset of the first and it has only some of the variables of the first. I would like to update the values in `dt_original` with the values from `dt_newdata`. For an added twist, I *only* want to update the values conditionally - in this case, only if the values in `dt_newdata` are larger than the corresponding values in `dt_original`.

For a reproducible example, here are the data. In the real world the tables are much larger:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0)

## This data.table with 20 rows and many variables is the existing data set
dt_original <- data.table(id = 1:20)
setkey(dt_original, id)

for(i in 2015:2017) {
  varA <- paste0('varA_', i)
  varB <- paste0('varB_', i)
  varC <- paste0('varC_', i)

  dt_original[, (varA) := rnorm(20)]
  dt_original[, (varB) := rnorm(20)]
  dt_original[, (varC) := rnorm(20)]
}

## This table with a strict subset of IDs from dt_original and only a part of
## the variables is our potential replacement data
dt_newdata <- data.table(id = sample(1:20, 3))
setkey(dt_newdata, id)

newdata_vars <- sample(names(dt_original)[-1], 4)

for(var in newdata_vars) {
  dt_newdata[, (var) := rnorm(3)]
}
```

Here is a way of doing it using a loop and `pmax`, but there has to be a better way, right?

```
for(var in newdata_vars) {
  k <- pmax(dt_newdata[, (var), with = FALSE], dt_original[id %in% dt_newdata$id, (var), with = FALSE])
  dt_original[id %in% dt_newdata$id, (var) := k, with = FALSE]
}
```

It seems like there should be a way using join syntax, and maybe the prefix `i.` and/or `.SD` or something like that, but nothing I've tried comes close enough to warrant repeating here.

Comment: Yeah, your pmax looks a lot like `dt_original[dt_newdata, on=.(id), pmax(x.varB, i.varB)]`, the only problem being the insistence on passing "varB" as a character... Probably solvable by putting your data in long format instead of wide.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to make this reproducible

Comment: Added `set.seed(0)`, thanks.

Comment: Think of `varB` as being a heterogeneous blend of several hundred variable names which is an arbitrary subset of the variables in `dt_original`. This example might make it look a little too regular.

Comment: Apologies for confusion, I made edits to the example to make the previous point more clear, now `newdata_vars` is more clearly an arbitrary subset of the variables. (Previously I just used the varB_yyyy variables).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the names are heterogeneous. They're apparently all numeric (judging by your use of pmax), which means they'd work very well together in a single column in a long-form data set. That is `melt(dt_original, id="id")`. From there, you'd probably also want to split the var name into component parts...(variable and year).  If you're interested in pursuing this, I'd recommend checking out Hadley's article on it: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work in the current format given your criteria.

```
dt_original[dt_newdata, names(dt_newdata) := Map(pmax, mget(names(dt_newdata)), dt_newdata)]
```

It joins to the IDs that match between the data.tables and then performs an assignment using `:=` Because we want to return a list, I use `Map` to run `pmax` through the columns of data.tables matching by the name of dt_newdata. Note that it is necessary that all names of dt_newdata are in dt_original data.

Following Frank's comment, you can remove the first column of the `Map` list items  and the column names using `[-1]` because they are IDs, which don't need to be computed. Removing the first column from `Map` avoids one pass of `pmax` and also preserves the key on id. Thanks to @brian-stamper for pointing out the key preservation in the comments.

```
dt_original[dt_newdata,
            names(dt_newdata)[-1] := Map(pmax,
                                         mget(names(dt_newdata)[-1]),
                                         dt_newdata[, .SD, .SDcols=-1])]
```

Note that the use of `[-1]` assumes that the ID variable is located in the first position of new_data. If it is elsewhere, you could change the index manually or use `grep`.

Comment: Yeah, looks alright. Dunno if you want it on *all* columns, though; might need to exclude `id`.

Comment: I think you might have had it right before the edit - I'm trying it both ways and with the `[-1]` it looks like `pmax` is trying to compare all rows of `dt_original` against `dt_newdata`.

Comment: OK. I returned the original code and then added working code for ignoring the id column.

Comment: Yes, that's it, most excellent. Interesting side note - if you don't skip the ID column this will wipe out the fact that it is a key, so you have to `setkey` again on the result (if you want keyed data). The `[-1]` version preserves the key.