# Canonical tidyverse method to update some values of a vector from a look-up table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, recode

I frequently need to recode some (not all!) values in a data frame column based off of a look-up table. I'm not satisfied by the ways I know of to solve the problem. I'd like to be able to do it in a **clear, stable, and efficient** way. Before I write my own function, I'd want to make sure I'm not duplicating something standard that's already out there.

```
## Toy example
data = data.frame(
  id = 1:7,
  x = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "AA", ".")
)

lookup = data.frame(
  old = c("A", "D", "."),
  new = c("a", "d", "!")
)

## desired result
#   id  x
# 1  1  a
# 2  2  a
# 3  3  B
# 4  4  C
# 5  5  d
# 6  6 AA
# 7  7  !
```

I can do it with a join, coalesce, unselect as below, but this **isn't as clear** as I'd like - too many steps.

```
## This works, but is more steps than I want
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = c("x" = "old")) %>%
  mutate(x = coalesce(new, x)) %>%
  select(-new)
```

It can also be done with `dplyr::recode`, as below, converting the lookup  table to a named lookup vector. I prefer `lookup` as a data frame, but I'm okay with the named vector solution. My concern here is that `recode` is the *Questioning* lifecycle phase, so I'm worried that this method **isn't stable**.

```
lookup_v = pull(lookup, new) %>% setNames(lookup$old)
data %>%
  mutate(x = recode(x, !!!lookup_v))
```

It could also be done with, say, `stringr::str_replace`, but using regex for whole-string matching **isn't efficient.** I suppose there is `forcats::fct_recode` is a stable version of `recode`, but I don't want a `factor` output (though `mutate(x = as.character(fct_recode(x, !!!lookup_v)))` is perhaps my  favorite option so far...).

I had hoped that the new-ish `rows_update()` family of `dplyr` functions would work, but it is strict about column names, and I don't think it can update the column it's joining on. (And it's *Experimental*, so doesn't yet meet my stability requirement.)

Summary of my requirements:

- A single data column is updated based off of a lookup data frame (preferably) or named vector (allowable)
- Not all values in the data are included in the lookup--the ones that are not present are not modified
- Must work on `character` class input. Working more generally is a nice-to-have.
- No dependencies outside of base R and `tidyverse` packages (though I'd also be interested in seeing a `data.table` solution)
- No functions used that are in lifecycle phases like superseded or questioning. Please note any experimental lifecycle functions, as they have future potential.
- Concise, clear code
- I don't need extreme optimization, but nothing wildly inefficient (like regex when it's not needed)

Comment: `data %>% mutate(x = str_replace_all(x, setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)))` is certainly less efficient than the matching and join, however, I'm not sure whether it's `wildly inefficient` with decent sized datasets.

Comment: Well, to be safe you'd need to use something like `sprintf("^%s$", lookup$new)` as the pattern, and even then I'd have concerns about regex special characters in the old names. I'm biased from an old project I used to work on where regex was a performance bottleneck (quite complex regex, mostly), but I definitely have a pet peeve about using regex for exact whole string matches. But on 100k rows my guess is `str_replace_all` will be at least 10x slower than most of these other solutions.

Comment: If the `recode` and `fct_recode` variants can't deal with `.`, then they're not general enough.

Answer (score 15):

A direct `data.table` solution, without `%in%`.
Depending on the length of the lookup / data tables, adding keys could improve performance substantially, but this isn't the case on this simple example.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
setDT(lookup)

## If needed
# setkey(data,x)
# setkey(lookup,old)

data[lookup, x:=new, on=.(x=old)]
data 

   id  x
1:  1  a
2:  2  a
3:  3  B
4:  4  C
5:  5  d
6:  6 AA
7:  7  !
```

Comment: This is the `data.table` solution I was looking for! Perfect! I didn't think it would work so nicely without a `coalesce` type step.

Comment: @Gregor, glad I could bring the `data.table` solution you were looking for! Would you mind putting `data.table` in the tags, as it also belongs to your question?

Comment: The best part? This code would have worked 8+ years ago, and it will likely work 10 years from today - the respect the `data.table` development team has for their users in regard to avoiding flippant name changes and frequent deprecations makes it a very stable solution compared to some other popular packages.

Answer (score 14):

### Benchmarking

Expanding the original dataset to 10M rows, 15 runs using microbenchmark gave the follow results on my computer:

Note that `forcats::fct_recode` and `dplyr::recode` solutions mentioned by the OP have also been included. Neither works with the updated data because the named vector that resolves to `. = !` will throw an error, which is why results are tested on the original dataset.

```
data = data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  x = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D")
)

lookup = data.frame(
  old = c("A", "D"),
  new = c("a", "d")
)

set.seed(1)
data <- data[sample(1:5, 1E7, replace = T),]

dt_lookup <- data.table::copy(lookup)

dplyr_coalesce <- function(){
  library(dplyr)
  lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)
  data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(x = coalesce(lookupV[ x ], x))
}

datatable_in <- function(){
  library(data.table)
  lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)
  setDT(dt_data)
  dt_data[ x %in% names(lookupV), x := lookupV[ x ] ]
}

datatable <- function(){
  library(data.table)
  
  setDT(dt_data)
  setDT(dt_lookup)
  
  ## If needed
  # setkey(data,x)
  # setkey(lookup,old)
  
  dt_data[dt_lookup, x:=new, on =.(x=old)]
}

purrr_modify_if <- function(){
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
  lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)
  data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(x = modify_if(x, x %in% lookup$old, ~ lookupV[.x]))
}

stringr_str_replace_all_update <- function(){
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)
  lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, do.call(sprintf, list("^\\Q%s\\E$", lookup$old)))
  
  data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(x = str_replace_all(x, lookupV))
}

base_named_vector <- function(){
  lookupV <- c(with(lookup, setNames(new, old)), rlang::set_names(setdiff(unique(data$x), lookup$old)))
  lookupV[data$x]
}

base_ifelse <- function(){
  lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)
  with(data, ifelse(x %in% lookup$old, lookup$new, x))
}

plyr_mapvalues <- function(){
  library(plyr)
  data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(x = plyr::mapvalues(x, lookup$old, lookup$new, warn_missing = F))
}

base_match <- function(){
  tochange <- match(data$x, lookup$old, nomatch = 0)
  data$x[tochange > 0] <- lookup$new[tochange]
}

base_local_safe_lookup <- function(){
  lv <- structure(lookup$new, names = lookup$old)
  
  safe_lookup <- function(val) {
    new_val <- lv[val]
    unname(ifelse(is.na(new_val), val, new_val))
  }
  
  safe_lookup(data$x)
}

dplyr_recode <- function(){
  library(dplyr)
  lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)
  
  data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(x = recode(x, !!!lookupV))
}

base_for <- function(){
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(lookup))) {
    data$x[data$x == lookup$old[i]] = lookup$new[i]
  }
}

datatable_for <- function(){
  library(data.table)
  setDT(dt_data)
  
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(lookup))) {
    dt_data[x == lookup$old[i], x := lookup$new[i]]
  }
}

forcats_fct_recode <- function(){
  library(dplyr)
  library(forcats)
  lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)
  
  data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(x = as.character(fct_recode(x, !!!lookupV)))
  
}

datatable_set <- function(){
  library(data.table)
  setDT(dt_data)
  
  tochange <- dt_data[, chmatch(x, lookup$old, nomatch = 0)]
  set(dt_data, i = which(tochange > 0), j = "x", value = lookup$new[tochange])
}

library(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(dplyr_coalesce(),
                        datatable(),
                        datatable_in(),
                        datatable_for(),
                        base_for(),
                        purrr_modify_if(),
                        stringr_str_replace_all_update(),
                        base_named_vector(),
                        base_ifelse(),
                        plyr_mapvalues(),
                        base_match(),
                        base_local_safe_lookup(),
                        dplyr_recode(),
                        forcats_fct_recode(),
                        datatable_set(),
                        times = 15L,
                        setup = dt_data <- data.table::copy(data))

bench$expr <- forcats::fct_rev(forcats::fct_reorder(bench$expr, bench$time, mean))
ggplot2::autoplot(bench)
```

[image]

Thanks to @Waldi and @nicola for advice implementing `data.table` solutions in the benchmark.

Comment: @LMc, interested to know how the new data.table solution I just posted compares to other solutions. I'm not sure `data <- copy(data)` is needed because microbenchmark creates anyway a new environment.

Comment: Sure the data.table solution should not count on having `copy` of a large object inside it. You can make a copy outside and pass that copy to the function and make a fairer comparison I guess.

Comment: You should exclude the `library` and `setDT` calls from the benchmark.

Answer (score 9):

Combination of a named vector and *coalesce*:

```
# make lookup vector
lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)

data %>% 
  mutate(x = coalesce(lookupV[ x ], x))
#   id x
# 1  1 a
# 2  2 a
# 3  3 B
# 4  4 C
# 5  5 d
```

Or *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
data[ x %in% names(lookupV), x := lookupV[ x ] ]
```

This post might have a better solution for data.table - "update on merge":

- [R data table: update join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44433451/680068)

Comment: You might use `tibble::deframe` to simplify it one step further: `mutate(data, x = coalesce(deframe(lookup)[x], x))`

Answer (score 8):

A `base R` option using <del>`%in%` and</del> `match` - thanks to @LMc & @nicola

```
tochange <- match(data$x, lookup$old, nomatch = 0)
data$x[tochange > 0] <- lookup$new[tochange]
```

---

One more `data.table` option using `set()` and `chmatch`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

tochange <- data[, chmatch(x, lookup$old, nomatch = 0)]
set(data, i = which(tochange > 0), j = "x", value = lookup$new[tochange])
```

Result

```
data
#  id  x
#1  1  a
#2  2  a
#3  3  B
#4  4  C
#5  5  d
#6  6 AA
#7  7  !
```

Answer (score 7):

### modify_if

You could use `purrr::modify_if` to only apply the named vector to values that exist in it. Though not a specified requirement, it has the benefit of the `.else` argument, which allows you to apply a different function to values not in your lookup.

I also wanted to include the use of `tibble::deframe` here to create the named vector. It is slower than `setNames`, though.

```
lookupV <- deframe(lookup)

data %>% 
  mutate(x = modify_if(x, x %in% lookup$old, ~ lookupV[.x]))
```

### str_replace_all

Alternatively, you could use `stringr::str_replace_all`, which can take a named vector for the `replacement` argument.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(x = str_replace_all(x, lookupV))
```

**Update**

To accommodate the change to your edited example, the named vector used in `str_replace_all` needs to be modified. In this way, the entire literal string needs to be match so that "A" does not get substituted in "AA", or "." does not replace everything:

```
lookupV <- setNames(lookup$new, do.call(sprintf, list("^\\Q%s\\E$", lookup$old)))

data %>% 
  mutate(x = str_replace_all(x, lookupV))
```

### left_join

Using `dplyr::left_join` this is very similar to OP solution, but uses `.keep` argument of `mutate` so it has less steps. This argument is currently in the *experimental* lifecycle and so it is not included in the benchmark (though it is around the middle of posted solutions).

```
left_join(data, lookup, by = c("x" = "old")) %>% 
    mutate(x = coalesce(new, x) , .keep = "unused")
```

### Base `R`

#### Named Vector

Create a substitution value for every unique value in your dataframe.

```
lookupV <- c(with(lookup, setNames(new, old)), setNames(nm = setdiff(unique(data$x), lookup$old)))

data$x <- lookupV[data$x]
```

#### ifelse

```
with(data, ifelse(x %in% lookup$old, lookupV[x], x))
```

Comment: Given the use of unnecessary regex and how slow `str_replace_all` is relative to other solutions, as you predicted I don't think it's a very viable option.

Comment: Also, I've never used `\Q` and `\E` in regex, so thanks for showing off that trick!

Answer (score 6):

Another option that is clear is to use a `for`-loop with subsetting to loop through the rows of the `lookup` table. This will almost always be quicker with `data.table` because of [auto indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html), or if you set the key (i.e., `?data.table::setkey()`) ahead of time. Also, it will--of course--get slower as the lookup table gets longer. I would guess an update-join would be preferred if there is a long lookup table.

Base R:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(lookup))) {
  data$x[data$x == lookup$old[i]] <- lookup$new[i]
}

data$x
# [1] "a"  "a"  "B"  "C"  "d"  "AA" "!"
```

Or the same logic with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(lookup))) {
  data[x == lookup$old[i], x := lookup$new[i]]
}

data$x
# [1] "a"  "a"  "B"  "C"  "d"  "AA" "!"
```

**Data**:

```
data = data.frame(
  id = 1:7,
  x = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "AA", ".")
)

lookup = data.frame(
  old = c("A", "D", "."),
  new = c("a", "d", "!")
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another base solution, with a lookup vector:

```
## Toy example
data = data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  x = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

lookup = data.frame(
  old = c("A", "D"),
  new = c("a", "d"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

lv <- structure(lookup$new, names = lookup$old)

safe_lookup <- function(val) {
  new_val <- lv[val]
  unname(ifelse(is.na(new_val), val, new_val))
}

data$x <- safe_lookup(data$x)
```

Answer (score 4):

dplyr+plyr solution that is in order with all ur bulletpoints (if u consider plyr in the the tidyverse):

```
data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    x = plyr::mapvalues(x, lookup$old, lookup$new) #Can add , F to remove warnings
  )
```

Comment: I consider the tidyverse to be all packages attached with the command `library(tidyverse)`, so I'm afraid not. Though I'm pretty sure it is on the dependency chain, so maybe it's marginal...

Comment: Ah, that's too bad, as it is quite an elegant solution (golf-coding, robustness, readability, and performance).

Answer (score 4):

I basically share the same problem. Although `dplyr::recode` is in the "questioning" life cycle I don't expect it to become deprecated. At some point it might be superseded, but even in this case it should still be usable. Therefore I'm using a wrapper around `dplyr::recode` which allows the use of named vectors and or two vectors (which could be a lookup table).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

recode2 <- function(x, new, old = NULL, .default = NULL, .missing = NULL) {
  
  if (!rlang::is_named(new) && !is.null(old)) {
    new <- setNames(new, old)
  }
  
  do.call(dplyr::recode,
          c(.x = list(x),
            .default = list(.default),
            .missing = list(.missing),
            as.list(new)))
  
}

data = data.frame(
  id = 1:7,
  x = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "AA", ".")
)

lookup = data.frame(
  old = c("A", "D", "."),
  new = c("a", "d", "!")
)

# two vectors new / old
data %>% 
  mutate(x = recode2(x, lookup$new, lookup$old))
#>   id  x
#> 1  1  a
#> 2  2  a
#> 3  3  B
#> 4  4  C
#> 5  5  d
#> 6  6 AA
#> 7  7  !

# named vector
data %>% 
  mutate(x = recode2(x, c("A" = "a",
                          "D" = "d",
                          "." = "!")))
#>   id  x
#> 1  1  a
#> 2  2  a
#> 3  3  B
#> 4  4  C
#> 5  5  d
#> 6  6 AA
#> 7  7  !
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another *base* variant using `setNames` making use that `[]` will take the first match.

```
data$x <- setNames(c(lookup$new, data$x), c(lookup$old, data$x))[data$x]

#dats$x <- c(setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old), setNames(data$x, data$x))[data$x] #Variant
#data$x <- (\(.) setNames(c(lookup$new, .), c(lookup$old, .))[.])(data$x) #Variant

data
#  id  x
#1  1  a
#2  2  a
#3  3  B
#4  4  C
#5  5  d
#6  6 AA
#7  7  !
```

In case `data$x` is not `character`.

```
data$x <- setNames(c(lookup$new, data$x), c(lookup$old, data$x))[as.character(data$x)]
```

The same but using `match`

```
data$x <- c(lookup$new, data$x)[match(data$x, c(lookup$old, data$x))]
```

or `fmatch`:

```
library(fastmatch)
data$x <- c(lookup$new, data$x)[fmatch(data$x, c(lookup$old, data$x))]
```

In case `data$x` is long and has many duplicates it might help to take only `unique`.

```
data$x <- (\(.) c(lookup$new, .)[match(data$x, c(lookup$old, .))])(unique(data$x))

#Unique and not in old
(\(.) c(lookup$new, .)[match(data$x, c(lookup$old, .))])(setdiff(data$x, lookup$old))

#Maybe faster as setdiff uses match for the whole vector
(\(.) c(lookup$new, .)[match(data$x, c(lookup$old, .))])(setdiff(unique(data$x), lookup$old))
```

And here `kit::funique` or `collapse::funique` could be a used instead of `unique`.

---

Anther way is the usage of `==` with `which` and usage of `rep`.

```
i <- lapply(lookup$old, \(s) which(s == data$x))
data$x[unlist(i)] <- rep(lookup$new, lengths(i))
```

---

When it is a character vector it could be stored as a `factor` and the `levels` of a factor can be renamed. (It was asked that this was not wanted but it could be very performant.)

```
x <- factor(data$x)

levels(x)[match(lookup$old, levels(x), nlevels(x)+1L)] <- lookup$new

x
#[1] a  a  B  C  d  AA ! 
#Levels: ! a AA B C d
```

---

Benchmark taking data from @LMc

```
data = data.frame(
  id = 1:7,
  x = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "AA", ".")
)

lookup = data.frame(
  old = c("A", "D", "."),
  new = c("D", "A", "!")
)

set.seed(1)
data <- data[sample(nrow(data), 1E7, replace = TRUE),]

library(data.table)
library(fastmatch)

dt_data <- data.table::copy(data)
system.time(setDT(dt_data))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.001       0.000       0.001 

dtK_data <- data.table::copy(data)
dtK_lookup <- data.table::copy(lookup)
system.time({
setDT(dtK_data)
setDT(dtK_lookup)
setkey(dtK_data, x)
setkey(dtK_lookup,old) })
#Note: dt uses multiple cores
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.373       0.067       0.141 

f_data <- data.table::copy(data)
system.time(f_data$x <- factor(f_data$x))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.238       0.032       0.270 

C0_data <- data.table::copy(data)

fun <- alist(coalesceDeframe = C0_data$x <- dplyr::coalesce(tibble::deframe(lookup)[data$x], data$x),
coalesce = C0_data$x <- dplyr::coalesce(setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)[data$x], data$x),
"recode" = C0_data$x <- dplyr::recode(data$x, !!!setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)),
mapvalues = C0_data$x <- plyr::mapvalues(data$x, lookup$old, lookup$new, FALSE),
"unique" = (\(.) C0_data$x <- c(lookup$new, .)[match(data$x, c(lookup$old, .))])(unique(data$x)),
"match0" = {i <- match(data$x, lookup$old, nomatch = 0)
  C0_data$x[i>0] <- lookup$new[i]},
"matchNA" = {i <- match(data$x, lookup$old)
  j <- which(!is.na(i))
  C0_data$x[j] <- lookup$new[i[j]]},
"rep" = {i <- lapply(lookup$old, \(s) which(s == data$x))
C0_data$x[unlist(i)] <- rep(lookup$new, lengths(i))},
"uniqueFmatch" = (\(.) C0_data$x <- c(lookup$new, .)[fmatch(data$x, c(lookup$old, .))])(unique(data$x)),
datatable = Cdt_data[lookup, x:=new, on=.(x=old)],
datatableKey = CdtK_data[dtK_lookup, x:=new, on=.(x=old)],
"collapseFmatch" = (\(.) C0_data$x <- c(lookup$new, .)[fmatch(data$x, c(lookup$old, .))])(collapse::funique(data$x)),
"kitFmatch" = (\(.) C0_data$x <- c(lookup$new, .)[fmatch(data$x, c(lookup$old, .))])(kit::funique(data$x)),
"factor" = levels(Cf_data$x)[match(lookup$old, levels(Cf_data$x), nlevels(Cf_data$x)+1L)] <- lookup$new
)

bench <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(list = fun, times = 7L,
    control=list(order="block"),
    setup = {Cdt_data <- data.table::copy(dt_data)
      CdtK_data <- data.table::copy(dtK_data)
      Cf_data <- data.table::copy(f_data)
      gc()
    })
bench
ggplot2::autoplot(bench, log=FALSE)
```

Result

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 coalesceDeframe 1419.85752 1431.90215 1441.67163 1437.54078 1456.58562 1457.32759     7
        coalesce 1416.81792 1418.58149 1422.67433 1420.02443 1424.95336 1434.80827     7
          recode 1162.67033 1163.04287 1168.39498 1163.63317 1168.59404 1189.18758     7
       mapvalues  613.99308  616.50627  618.56250  617.50594  617.96866  629.48865     7
          match0  369.73388  379.07043  390.64808  385.51089  403.51618  414.11857     7
         matchNA  360.17730  375.59077  378.24535  376.08590  385.57151  389.12971     7
             rep  351.87641  352.77764  364.34904  357.27131  375.93110  383.87809     7
          unique  340.98122  341.27901  341.87930  341.63321  342.35865  343.26537     7
    uniqueFmatch  253.75138  253.90585  254.33802  254.14054  254.73900  255.18455     7
       datatable  237.79038  252.08057  251.22063  253.78246  254.10755  254.59535     7
    datatableKey  165.42183  165.55716  166.01792  165.68011  166.34137  167.22646     7
  collapseFmatch  125.93940  126.10227  126.25538  126.13199  126.42614  126.65943     7
       kitFmatch  125.72638  125.94671  127.43846  126.16227  126.96446  134.35822     7
          factor   39.35195   39.43222   39.45809   39.44678   39.47576   39.59197     7
```

[image: Timings of different methods]

In this case using a `factor` and updating it's `levels` is fastest. Using a fast version of `unique` improves speed substantially.