# Match a string from one column to another and substitute it by the string in the next column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing in some columns strings of crop names that have spelling mistakes. Then I have another dataframe with all the "unique" strings with mistakes in the first dataframe and the corrected spelling next to it. I would like to make new columns with the corrected strings.

The original dataframe with spelling mistakes could look like this:

```
crops_A <- c(NA, "wheat", "wheet", "rice", "olifs")
crops_B <- c("olives", "maize", NA, "maisse", NA)
crops_C <- c("corn", "barly", "wheat", "rice", NA)
other_columns <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
original_df <- data.frame(crops_A, crops_B, crops_C, other_columns)
```

Then from columns crops_A, B, and C I have all the "unique" spellings and a corrected column in a new dataframe:

```
original_unique <- c("wheat", "wheet", "rice", "olifs", "olives", "maize", "maisse", "corn", "barly")
corrected <- c("wheat", "wheat", "rice", "olives", "olives", "maize", "maize", "maize", "barley")
data.frame(original_unique, corrected)
```

| original_unique | corrected |
| --- | --- |
| wheat | wheat |
| wheet | wheat |
| rice | rice |
| olifs | olives |
| olives | olives |
| maize | maize |
| maisse | maize |
| corn | maize |
| barly | barley |

My desired output would look something like this:

```
crops_A <- c(NA, "wheat", "wheet", "rice", "olifs")
crops_B <- c("olives", "corn", "NA", "maisse", NA)
crops_C <- c("corn", "barly", "wheat", "rice", NA)
crops_A_corr <- c(NA, "wheat","wheat", "rice", "olives")
crops_B_corr <- c("olives", "maize", NA, "maize", NA)
crops_C_corr <- c("maize", "barley", "wheat", "rice", NA)
output_df <- dataframe(crops_A, crops_A_corr, crops_B, crops_B_corr, crops_C, crops_C_corr)
```

| crops_A | crops_A_corr | crops_B | crops_B_corr | crops_C | crops_C_corr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | olives | olives | corn | maize |
| wheat | wheat | corn | maize | barly | barley |
| wheet | wheat | NA | NA | wheat | wheat |
| rice | rice | maisse | maize | rice | rice |
| olifs | olives | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I have tried with `str_match` but the lengths are different and I can't do the match.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm disappointed there isn't helper function to do this directly from a lookup table, but [I asked a similar question a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67081496/903061) and this uses one of the answers I like more:

```
fixes = data.frame(original_unique, corrected)

lookup <- setNames(fixes$corrected, fixes$original_unique)

original_df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("crops"), \(x) coalesce(lookup[x], x)))
#   crops_A crops_B crops_C other_columns
# 1    <NA>  olives   maize             1
# 2   wheat   maize  barley             2
# 3   wheat    <NA>   wheat             3
# 4    rice   maize    rice             4
# 5  olives    <NA>    <NA>             5
```

You can use `.names = '{.col}_corr'` in `across()` if you want to keep the old columns.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## create named lookup vector:
lookup <- setNames(corrected, original_unique)

original_df |>
    mutate(across(starts_with('crops'),
                  ~ lookup[.x],
                  .names = '{.col}_corrected'
                  )
           ) |>
    ## relocate columns to have COL_corrected follow COL:
    (\(.) select(., names(.) |> order()))()
```

```
##   crops_A crops_A_corrected crops_B crops_B_corrected crops_C crops_C_corrected other_columns
## 1    <NA>              <NA>  olives            olives    corn             maize             1
## 2   wheat             wheat   maize             maize   barly            barley             2
```

**Edit** column relocation is now done with `select` instead of the initial pivot > sort > pivot-back chain as suggested by Gregor Thomas