# non-equi join does not preserve original column values

Tags: r, join, data.table, tidyverse, non-equi-join

I've found an odd behavior when running a non-equi join (from R's data.table library) and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Why is it that, when running a non-equi join, if I want to preserve the original value of the left table, I need to write `x.colname` instead of just `colname` inside the `j` attribute of the join?

Here's a small reproducible example of what I'm talking about:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Setting seed for reproducibility
set.seed(666)

# data.table that contains roadway segments.
# The "frm_dfo" and "to_dfo" columns represent the start and end mileposts 
# of each roadway segment. For example, the segment with road_ID=101 refers 
# to the portion of IH20 that starts at milepost 10 and ends at milepost 20.
roads = data.table(road_id=101:109,
                   hwy=c('IH20','IH20','IH20','SH150','SH150','SH150','TX66','TX66','TX66'),
                   frm_dfo=c(10,20,30,10,20,30,10,20,30),
                   to_dfo=c(20,30,40,20,30,40,20,30,40),
                   seg_name=c('Seg 1','Seg 2', 'Seg 3','Seg 10','Seg 20', 'Seg 30','Seg 100','Seg 200', 'Seg 300'))

# data.table that contains crashes. 
# The "dfo" column represents the milepost of the roadway on which the 
# crash occurs. For example, the crash with crash_id=1 happens on milepost 33.23105 of IH20.
crashes = data.table(crash_id=1:30,
                     hwy=rep(c('IH20','SH150','BOB11'),each=10),
                     dfo=runif(min=10,max=40, n=30))

# Non-equi join that finds which segment each crash happens on.
joined_data_v1 = crashes %>%
                  .[roads, 
                    j  = list(crash_id, hwy, x.dfo, seg_name, frm_dfo, to_dfo),
                    on = list(hwy=hwy, dfo >= frm_dfo, dfo <= to_dfo)] %>%
                  arrange(crash_id, by_group = TRUE)

# Again, joining crashes and roadway segments. 
# Here, though, note that I've swapped x.dfo for just dfo inside the `j` argument 
joined_data_v2 = crashes %>%
                  .[roads, 
                    j  = list(crash_id, hwy, dfo, seg_name, frm_dfo, to_dfo),
                    on = list(hwy=hwy, dfo >= frm_dfo, dfo <= to_dfo)] %>%
                  arrange(crash_id, by_group = TRUE)
```

Here is a snapshot of `joined_data_v1` (using `x.dfo` in the `j` argument):
[image: joined_data_v1]

And here is a snapshot of `joined_data_v2` (using `dfo` in the `j` argument):
[image: joined_data_v2]

Note how, in `joined_data_v1`, the column called `x.dfo` contains the exact values from the `dfo` column from the `crashes` data.table. However, in `joined_data_v2`, the column called `dfo` contains the values from the `frm_dfo` column from the `roads` data.table (instead of the actual data from the `crashes` data.table's `dfo` column).

What is going on here? Why does this behave so oddly? Why do the values contained in the `dfo/x.dfo` column of the resulting data.table not always reflect exactly what was contained in the original `dfo` column from the `crashes` data.table?

I tried looking into some of the documentation for the non-equi join, but couldn't really find anything that could help me here.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473644/how-to-keep-join-column-unchanged-in-data-table-non-equi-join) is a related related question, but they don't mention **why** this behavior happens.

Comment: I share the curiosity, but I fear this will be mostly about *opinion*, unless the originating authors choose to weigh in with their original design decisions. This has been brought up before; despite many of the authors being active on SO, they appear to have not weighed in, either due to inattention or not wishing to get into the discussion. My *guess* is that something had to be chosen, and there were several not-unreasonable alternatives, and they chose one at the time. Perhaps they regret, but it is really hard to change that default behavior without breaking *a lot of depending packages*.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Yeah, sounds like they had a hard decision to make. On a related note: do you happen to know what exactly that `x.` prefix is supposed to mean/do? Or where I can find more information about when it's needed or where else it is useful? I wasn't able to find much when I searched package's docs. Thx again!

Comment: Nope, no idea about the `x.` prefix, sorry. Often my exploits in non-trivial `[`-joins (non-equi or otherwise) require iteration through many similar attempts to find what I want; this includes names and values of non-equi columns.

Comment: No worries. Still, thanks for the helpful info!!! =)

Comment: I think the `.x` comes from the merging nomentlature: your are subsetting a data.table `x` with an other data.table, by placing it in the `i` part of the `x[i,j,by]` structure. So the calling `.i` refers to columns in the second one, and `.x` in the first one. You can do an update join using `.i`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433451/r-data-table-update-join

Comment: you might want to check out https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1700 . And you dont need non-equi join to get this behaviour
`a <- data.table(x=4:5);
b <- data.table(y=1);
a[b, on=.(x=y), .(x, y)];
a[b, on=.(x=y), .(x.x, i.y)]` my rudimentary understanding is that j will use values from i when they are also keys used in the join.

Comment: A bit more explanations : https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44343424/13513328

Comment: I think this is the canonical PR where the background of your issue is discussed: [SQL-like column return for non-equi and rolling joins](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3093). (The PR is marked as closed, but I reckon it's "just" because it's transferred to [Both columns for rolling and non-equi joins](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3093))